# PostgreSQL CROSS JOIN query issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join

I would like to improve the following query:

```
WITH calendar as (
      SELECT d
      FROM generate_series(
'2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2020-12-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month'
) d
     )
     
SELECT c.d::date AS ord_date,
       n.id,
       coalesce(nb_cit,0) as nb_cit
FROM (SELECT distinct t.id from "data".taxonomie t where id = '30092') n CROSS JOIN
     calendar c
left join 
(select date_trunc('month', i2.date_d) as mon, count(c2.id) as nb_cit
from "data".inventaire i2, "data".citation c2 where i2.id = c2.id_inv and c2.id_taxo = '30092'
group by mon) s
on c.d = s.mon
```

It works when I set an id (in the from and left join). But the idea is to have the result for all the id.

If I don't set this identifier, I get the same result whatever the identifier is.
I think I have to take out the "count(c2.id)" from the left join but I can't figure how to do it.

Help would be welcome !

Best Regards,
Mathias

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to aggregate by the id as well in the subquery:

```
SELECT c.d::date AS ord_date,
       n.id,
       coalesce(s.nb_cit, 0) as nb_cit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.id FROM "data".taxonomie t) n CROSS JOIN
     calendar c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c2.id_taxo, date_trunc('month', i2.date_d) as mon, count(c2.id) as nb_cit
      FROM "data".inventaire i2 JOIN
           "data".citation c2 
           ON i2.id = c2.id_inv 
      GROUP BY c2.id_taxo, mon
     ) s
     ON c.d = s.mon AND n.id = s.id_taxo;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. I was stuck since yesterday! This is exactly what I wanted to do.